# what can I do on Jenkinsfile to get credentials?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

I'm new to jenkins and I'm creating a jenkinsfile with a declarative pipeline that supports different parameters. I also need to access to a credential stored in Jenkins, that I created already. How can I access to this credentials though jenkinsfile? do I need to call them inside of the stage or like this is ok? I got very confused in this part :S

I saw something like this on internet:

```
steps {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'x'....

      }
```

Until now I have this:

```
    pipeline {
        agent any

        environment{
            my_credentials = credentials('x-credentials-id')
        }
        stages{
            stage('Setup parameters') {
                steps {
                        parameters([
                            string(name: 'a', defaultValue: 'x', description: 'test'),
                            text(name: 'b', defaultValue: ''),
                            text(name: 'b2', defaultValue: ''),
                            text(name: 'c', defaultValue: ''),
                            text(name: 'c2', defaultValue: '')
                        ])
                    //])
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From Jenkins documentation.

> Jenkins' declarative Pipeline syntax has the credentials() helper
> method (used within the environment directive) which supports secret
> text, username and password, as well as secret file credentials.

So basically `credentials('x-credentials-id')` will support the aforementioned credential types and you should be using this helper method within an Environment block. You can use this approach if you want to declare your credentials globally so they can be used anywhere in the pipeline.

example

```
environment {
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = credentials('jenkins-aws-secret-key-id')
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('jenkins-aws-secret-access-key')
    }
```

For other types, you can use `withCredentials` directive.(This is coming from Credentials Binding plugin) Both will get the Job done.

```
withCredentials(bindings: [certificate(credentialsId: 'jenkins-certificate-for-xyz', \
                                                       keystoreVariable: 'CERTIFICATE_FOR_XYZ', \
                                                       passwordVariable: 'XYZ-CERTIFICATE-PASSWORD')]) {
                  // 
                }
```

Although it says secrettext, username and password etc are not supported with Bind Credentials plugin, you can use WithCredentials for those types as well.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'amazon', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
  echo "username is $USERNAME"
}
```

Read more from [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/) and [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials)